# sorting array with many duplicates of 10 distinct integers in linear time

Tags: sorting, data-structures, computer-science

I was doing my homework and stuck in one of the questions that ask about sorting in linear time. Below is the question.

5. Suppose you have an array A of n integers with many duplicates, and you are told that there are at most 10 distinct integers in A.
   Give a linear-time algorithm to sort array A using the comparison-based model for sorting.
   You may not use Hashing or any other value-based linear time sorting algorithm like Bucket Sort or Redix Sort.

Comment: Hello, and welcome. What language are you using for your homework? What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow has a good FAQ on [how to ask useful questions about homework assignments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3025856), which I'd recommend reviewing.

Comment: I have to answer as a description of an algorithm.

Comment: Consider that Quicksort's partitioning method is O(n).